# Cannot reuse HTTP connection for different host

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube

При скачивании видео ffmpeg'ом командой

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls -i smth.m3u8 -codec copy smth.mp4
```

Периодически вижу сообщение:

> Cannot reuse HTTP connection for different host:

[image: скриншот]

Вроде бы вполне логично, что если хост другой, то требуется другое соединение и ситуация должна быть штатной. Однако, ffmpeg почему-то выводит эту запись красным как ошибку и следующий блок жёлтым.

**Так это нормально или при скачивании пропускается фрагмент?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрел внимательнее на ссылки - похоже, всё нормально:

[image: скриншот]